# Using a word reserved for a property VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a VBA project that imports data from a secure website.
I've found a little trouble that I just can't figure out how to solve it. 
When I intend to provide the username info, VBA will read as the .UserName property. I would like to know how can I use the "username" word without it being read as a property.

Example

How it is (VBA corrects automatically to that):

```
With ieDoc.forms(0)
.UserName.Value = "montemor"
.Password.Value = "example"
.submit
```

How it should be:

```
With ieDoc.forms(0)
.username.Value = "montemor"
.password.Value = "example"
.submit
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: VBA is case-insensitive - `UserName` and `username` are both the exact same identifier name as far as the compiler is concerned. the VBE will "correct" the casing of all matching identifier names, specifically *because* it doesn't care about the case. Do `Dim USERNAME` and suddenly your `username` and `UserName` all become `USERNAME` - that's just how it is, and whether it's `username`, `UserName`, or `USERNAME`, as far as VBA cares *it's all the same* - i.e. it's not because you see `UserName` that you're magically accessing the `UserName` property of a completely unrelated other thing.

Comment: How does this have a detrimental effect on your code? Seems to me that this is some form of OCD - but it can't be because your OCD would have made you indent your lines under your `With` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Type somewhere in code `Dim UserName` - and your property will be corrected.

Comment: The property will not be corrected, because that code accesses a property of the Form, not of the Module or main code. With the above code written the way it is, it doesn't matter how many variable declarations are made, the VBA IDE will always resort to the same behaviour.

Comment: @AJD I think you're missing the point and getting just as confused as the OP. VBA is case-insensitive. This answer explains exactly what to do to "fix" the casing of declarations. One given identifier (e.g. `username`) can only ever exist in one casing, throughout whatever is loaded in the VBE. `USERNAME` and `UserName` and `username` are all the same identifier, regardless of whether one being a constant, another being a property and the other being a class name - it makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @Mat'sMug = yes I know that VBA is case insensitive. But the above code addresses a form property, and I thought that the VBA IDE automatically corrects for that (this is part of my process to check for typos). I will have to check at some stage when I have time (not right at the moment)

Comment: @Mat'sMug In addition - the OP does not want this addressed as a Property, so trying to correct the property itself doesn't achieve the outcome.

Comment: @AJD I might be misreading the OP, but between "I have this:" and "should be this:" blocks in the OP, the only difference I'm seeing is the casing, which doesn't make any difference because, as you know, VBA is case-insensitive. Therefore I assumed OP was thinking the VBE "correcting" identifier casing was a problem (and it isn't).

Comment: @Mat'sMug: I am taking my queue from: "I would like to know how can I use the "username" word without it being read as a property. " :-)

Answer (score -1):

You using it within a `With` construct (with a `.`) so the VBA is doing exactly as you are telling it to do - accessing the Form property.

If you also have a variable called `username`, then you can drop the `.` in front of that line. But then, you also don't want to encapsulate that within the `With` construct unless there is something else in your code that requires it.

EDIT: This answers the part of OP which states: "I would like to know how can I use the "username" word without it being read as a property. "